# Condição IF conforme seleção do campo option

Tags: javascript, if, html-option

Sou novo em programação, estou com um problema em meu código:

```js
var micro = "Micro Inversores";

if (micro.equals(document.getElementById("tipo_unidade"))) {
    var tipo1 = 1;
else
    var tipo1 = 0.8;
}
```

```html
<select id="tipo_unidade" name="tipo_unidade" onchange="MudaLabeL('compl_Preco_1',txt_qtd_1.value)" style="width:660px">
    <option value="Micro Inversores">Micro Inversores</option>
    <option value="Inversor Tradicional">Inversor Tradicional</option>
```

Tenho um campo `<option>` onde o usuário seleciona uma opção, conforme a seleção dele, preciso que o valor da variável `tipo1` seja `0.8` ou `1`.

Tentei também:

```js
var char micro = "Micro Inversores";

if (micro = p_classe) {
    var tipo = 1;
else
    var tipo = 0.8;
}

document.getElementById("p_classe").innerHTML = (classeundValue);

function atualizaclasse() {
    var classeund = document.getElementById("tipo_unidade");
    classeundValue = classeund.value;
}
```

Se eu retirar a parte da condição `if` e definir, por exemplo `var tipo = 1;`, o código funciona perfeitamente. Meu problema está em definir esse valor de `0.8` ou `1` para a variável tipo, conforme a seleção do usuário.

Comment: Creio que precise pegar o valor do select com .value: `document.getElementById("tipo_unidade").value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Montei um exemplo com o `value` como o @Sam disse

```js
var micro = "Micro Inversores";
var valor = 0; // Veja que eu coloquei a variável valor em um escopo global

 function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
  if (elem.addEventListener)
   elem.addEventListener (eventType, handler, false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent)
   elem.attachEvent ('on' + eventType, handler); 
 }

 addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById('tipo_unidade'), 'change', function() {
   if (document.getElementById("tipo_unidade").value == micro) {
    valor = 1;
   } else {
    valor = 0.8;
   }
   console.log(valor);
   document.getElementById('compl_Preco_1').value = valor;
  });
 });
```

```html
<select id="tipo_unidade" name="tipo_unidade" style="width:660px">
    <option value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
 <option value="Micro Inversores">Micro Inversores</option>
 <option value="Inversor Tradicional">Inversor Tradicional</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="compl_Preco_1">
```

Comment: Vejo que seu código funciona aqui no stackoverflow, está um pouco complexo pra mim, mas enfim, o resultado é que você atribui 1 para a variável "valor" se tipo_unidade for igual a micro e 0.8 se não for, quando eu coloco ele no cód, tudo é executado normalmente sem erros, porém se eu usar essa variável "valor" na fórmula, ai o cód n executa nada.

var Total = ((Material*(valor)) + MObra + imposto + Frete + Liq + Projeto + RT + DespesasGerais + DespesasCabDisj) * 1;

Comment: A variável `valor` não existe fora do escopo da função, ou seja, ela só existe ali naquele `if` o que você pode fazer é colocar a variável `valor` em outro escopo, vou alterar a resposta e colocar dessa nova maneira, assim acredito que você vai conseguir usar

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem sua questão, você poderia utilizar os valores que precisa como `value` de cada `option`:

```
<select id="tipo_unidade" name="tipo_unidade" onchange="MudaLabeL('compl_Preco_1',txt_qtd_1.value)" style="width:660px">
    <option value="1">Micro Inversores</option>
    <option value="0.8">Inversor Tradicional</option>
</select>
```

Daí:

```
let tipo = parseFloat(document.getElementyById('tipo_unidade').value);
```

Não testei, mas acredito que seja o caminho. (Dentro do que entendi da sua questão.)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function teste(a) {
     var micro = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);  
     var tipo1 = 0;
     
     if (micro == "Micro Inversores"){
           tipo1 = 1;
     }else if(micro == "Inversor Tradicional"){
           tipo1 = 0.8;
     }else{
           tipo1 = 0;
     }
    
    document.getElementById('compl_Preco_1').value = tipo1;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="teste(this)" id="tipo_unidade" name="tipo_unidade"  style="width:660px">
      <option value="">-Selecione</option>
     <option value="Micro Inversores">Micro Inversores</option>
     <option value="Inversor Tradicional">Inversor Tradicional </option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="compl_Preco_1">
```

Answer (score 0):

muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, por incrível que pareça, era algo bobo no cód (como sempre) que estava fazendo tudo dar errado.

```
        #COMO FUNCIONOU ↓
        var micro = "Micro Inversores";
        if (document.getElementById("tipo_unidade").value == micro) {
            var tipon = 1;
        } else {
            var tipon = 0.8;
        }

        #CÓDIGO DANDO PROBLEMAS ↓
        var micro = "Micro Inversores";
        if (micro.equals(document.getElementById("tipo_unidade"))) {
        var tipo1 = 1;
        else
        var tipo1 = 0.8;
        }
```

Não cheguei a testar com o equals, a regra é clara, se funcionou deixa funcionando (haha), mas eu tinha esquecido de fechar e abrir chaves no if '-' } else {

Criei uma tempestade num copo d'água, mas de toda forma, muito obrigado por tentarem me ajudar!!